# how to remove words from text using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to remove words from text that are not English. I used nltk's words corpus but it's worse than the 'enchant' library.

Creating my own text dictionary would require a lot of time and thinking.

Enchant is case sensitive to proper nouns e.g. it would return False for firefox and True for Firefox, my text is all converted to lower case. Can the enchant library somehow be case insensitive for proper nouns?

Edit: I thought about it and observed that enchant lib returns true for any english word that has a capital first letter. So I just convert every word's first letter to capital using python's title() method and the results improve.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I do not think this is possible in general. A word that looks like an English word may actually be an homograph from another languages. Then, how about proper nouns? Do you want to consider Korean company names (like Samsung) as English words? How about Russian companies? If so, do you even know all Korean/Russian company names?

Comment: @rosh I just iterate over all the words in a text file checking if enchant.Dict("en").check("word") returns true or false

Comment: @DYZ what about the case sensitive issue can it be solved somehow?

Comment: Case doesn't matter. If there is a word "lot" in you text, do you keep it because it is English, or do you remove it because it is Polish? (It's both.) Is Toyota an English word? Then how about Toyoda? (The original Japanese spelling of "Toyota.") Unless you have a clear definition of an "English word," the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: @DYZ I would keep 'lot' cause it's english. Is there a way to make enchant case insensitive?